# Separate elements divided by comma in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of strings that contains elements of the type

```
List=['name1,vol', 'name1,price','name2, vol', 'name2,price'.... ]
```

I would like to extract a list only of "names" which are the parts that actually change as the second components in each element have a fix pattern (here:vol, price). Notice that the "names" can obviously have different length. To sum up, I'd like to extract something like:

```
List_names=['name1', 'name2' ]
```

How can I do that?

What if I have something of the type:

```
List_tricky=[('name1', 'vol'), ('name1', 'price'),('name2', 'vol'), ('name2', 'price').... ]
```

Comment: What have you attempted that doesn't work?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Jab's answer did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn it into a dict then back into a list using `str.split`. (No loop required as it does it efficiently for you) Use `functools.partial` to apply the split to each string instead of a lambda:

```
from functools import partial
list(dict(map(partial(str.split, sep=','), List)))
```

---

This works for either input but way more simple for the list of tuples:

```
>>> l = ['name1,vol', 'name1,price','name2, vol', 'name2,price'.... ]
>>> list(dict(map(partial(str.split, sep=','), List)))
['name1', 'name2']
```

---

```
>>> l = [('name1', 'vol'), ('name1', 'price'),('name2', 'vol'), ('name2', 'price').... ] 
>>> list(dict(l))
['name1', 'name2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
List=['name1,vol', 'name1,price','name2, vol', 'name2,price']

names = []

for string in List:

    name = string.split(',')[0]

    names.append(name)

print(names)
```

For your 'tricky' case, you can try:

```
# initialize variables:
names = []

# iterate over each point (tuple):
for point in List:

    # get name:
    name = point[0]

    # append to list:
    names.append(name)

print(names)
```

Comment: you probably need to `names.sort()` and `set (names)` at the end.

Comment: it works very well @Daniel ! Thanks! I edited the question with a more tricky case. I hope you guys can help me in this case too

Comment: No problem - I've updated my answer - let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Similar logic to @Daniel Sokol's answer , you can use a one liner :

```
list2 = [x.split(',')[0] for x in List]
```

Comment: other perfect and very parsimonious solution!

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of @Alireza Tajadod's already wonderful answer, you might want to apply conversion to a set, then back to a list to remove any possible duplication items, as suggested by @Cryptoharf84 in the comments.

```py
names_list = list(set([entry.split(',')[0] for entry in List]))
```

The same logic with list comprehension can be applied to the trickier case.

```py
names_list_2 = list(set([entry[0] for entry in List_tricky]))
```

To make list comprehension more explicit, you can also do the following:

```py
names_list_3 = list(set([name for name, _ in List_tricky]))
```

The `_` indicates that we are discarding the second value of the unpacked tuple.

Sets are useful because converting a list with duplicate elements into a set effectively removes any duplications.

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, look for naming conventions in python. But never name variables starting with upper case, nor with existing class names.

I will try something like:

```
list_names = [s.split(',')[0].strip() for s in List]
list_unique_names(set(list_names))
```

split returns a list of "chunks" of the original string, and strip to remove whitespaces on beginning/end of the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

I will change your data structure to `dict` instead of `list`

```
d={'name1': ('vol', 'price'),'name2': ('vol', 'price'), .... }
```

In order to get just the names:
`d.keys()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `.map()` function:

```
# Case 1: List
all_names = map(lambda x :a.split(',')[0], List)

# Case 2: List_tricky
all_names = [i[0] for i in List_tricky]

# After the code is the same
unique_names = set(all_names)
List_names = list(unique_names)
print(List_names)
```